# How do I "log" the M most recent images from a webcam using the command-line?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, webcam, drivers

I want to take a picture with the webcam every *N* time units and store it to */tmp/somefolder/* for further use with other tools and only keep the last *M* images. 
How to do this using *webcam*(UNIX COMMAND)? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this utilities: camgrab webcam

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV?

Comment: Thanks @Mitch
But the OpenCV is kind of overkill for just grabbing few frames.
anyways ,Thanks 4 the help again.

Comment: @konrad if its an answer, you may want to post it.

Answer (score 1):

Well ,why don't you try `uvccapture` or `fswebcam` both are an excellent choices.

For using uvccapture, install using `sudo apt-get install uvccapture` and to use 
`uvvcaputure -m -q100 -x640 -y480 -opic.jpg` where pic.jpg is the filename.
Similarly install fswebcam and to use `fswebcam $filename,`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `webcam`. Here you find more info regarding webcam https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam