# How to usewebcam CLI

Tags: command-line, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I “log” the M most recent images from a webcam using the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156110/how-do-i-log-the-m-most-recent-images-from-a-webcam-using-the-command-line)

I am new to ubuntu and am trying to capture a frame from usb webcam using *webcam* cli.
can you please tell me how to do that.
how to pass the config parameters to the api.
Any help appreciated.